# How can I replace all relative image path into absolute path form a css

Tags: php, css

I want to replace all relative background-image path into absolute path. After trying that so much time, I've failed to solve this. My current code only solves the last image path. I'm using a path resolver function(from this reference:[url_to_absolute()](http://publicmind.in/blog/urltoabsolute/))in this code.

```
<?php

require './url_to_absolute.php';
$css = "
    .selector1{
        background-image:url(../dir1/images/image.jpg);
        width:100%;
    }
    .selector2{
        background-image:url(\"../dir1/images/image2.jpg\");
        color:black;
    }
    .selector3{
        background-image:url( 'dir1/images/image3.jpg' );
        text-align:left;
    }
    .selector4{
        background-image:url( \"dir1/images/image4.jpg\" );
        text-align:left;
    }           
" ;
$base_url = 'http://www.example.com/'; 

$pattern  = "/(?<=\()(.*?)(?=\))/s";
preg_match_all($pattern, $css, $matches);

foreach($matches[1] as $url){
        $url = trim($url);
        $url = str_replace("\"", "", $url);
        $url = str_replace("'", "", $url);
        $full_path = url_to_absolute($base_url, $url);
        $new_css = str_replace($url, $full_path, $css);     
}
print $new_css;

?>
```

It generates the result -

```
.selector1{ background-image:url(../dir1/images/image.jpg); width:100%; } 
.selector2{ background-image:url("../dir1/images/image2.jpg"); color:black; } 
.selector3{ background-image:url( 'dir1/images/image3.jpg' ); text-align:left; } 
.selector4{ background-image:url( "http://www.example.com/dir1/images/image4.jpg" ); text-align:left; }
```

Advice me please.

Comment: show the full path where your image is residing.

Comment: @Truth Thanks for comment, but that can solve only server side path (C:\Inetpub\testweb\test.txt) [func_filesystem_realpath](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_realpath.asp)

Comment: http: //www.example.com is a root folder,, i confuse with ../  do you mean this with 1level up from root folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I appreciate the accepted answer for its cleverness, it might be one of the most complex function that I've seen in PHP...

This one if much easier to grasp (adapt regex to your needs):

```
function urlsToAbsolute($baseUrl, $html) {

    preg_match_all('/(href="|src=")([^"#]+)(")/i', $html, $matches);

    foreach ($matches[2] as $num => $match) {
        $codec[$match] = url_to_absolute($baseUrl, $match);
    }

    return strtr($html, $codec);
}
```

Comment: Hi @Joan-Diego Rodriguez, So many thanks for this easy, small and clean code. One of my project still using that prior method. Soon I will replace that code.

Comment: I'm a bit baffled, how can one simple function call ([`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/manual/function.preg-replace-callback.php)) *be one of the most complex function* that you've seen? Also, when would `href` or `src` be ever used in a css file?